# How to implement a generic interface with defined return types

Tags: c#

I have an interface for my geometric shapes that looks like this:

```
public interface IGeometry
{
    T Translate<T>(in v2 vector) where T : IGeometry;
    T MoveTo<T>(in v2 vector) where T : IGeometry;
}
```

I am confused how i define this in my structs where i specifically return the struct type that implements the interface. I have this in my `Circle : IGeometry` struct:

```
public readonly struct Circle : IGeometry
{
    public readonly v2 _o;
    public readonly double _r, _area, _circum;
    public v2 Origin => _o;
    public double Radius => _r;
    public double Circumference => _circum;

    public Circle(in v2 origin, in double radius)
    {
        _o = origin;
        _r = radius;
        _area = _r * _r * Math.PI;
        _circum = _r * 2 * Math.PI;
    }

    public T Translate<T>(in v2 translation) => new(_o + translation, _r);
    public T MoveTo<T>(in v2 position) => new(position, _r);
}
```

The error i get however is:

```
Error CS0425: The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'Circle.Translate<T>(in v2)' 
must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 
'IGeometry.Translate<T>(in v2)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.
```

Not quite sure I understand how to fix this.

Comment: Did you mean to make `IGeometry` generic instead? `public interface IGeometry<T> where T: IGeometry<T>`, and `Circle` would implement `IGeometry<Circle>`.

Comment: No because if i did, it would screw up my collision function which accepts IGeometry for which i use a switch on to find out which two geometric types are colliding.

Comment: Well then you should include that "collision function" of yours into the question then.

Comment: That's a huge function, hundreads of lines checking multiple pairs of geometry types and kind've out of the scope of the problem. I just want my geometry shapes to have shared functions from the IGeometry interface but their return types need to be the actual geometry type in question not `IGeometry`. So a Circle returns Circle a Triangle returns Triangle etc.

Comment: I didn't see these comments before posting my answer, but if you need to be able to still have `IGeometry` without the generic, you can add that as a second interface that the generic version always implements and continue to use it where needed.

Comment: Actually, if you are already using `switch`es in your collision function, you already threw generics out of the window, you might as well just do `new Circle(...)` and cast the return value to `T`. That said, a better design would be to put the collision logic in the shapes themselves (perhaps the shapes themselves can return some numbers relevant to collision detection), instead of writing a "huge function" for it.

Comment: If i put them in the shapes then you get duplication for Circle.Intersects(Square) and Square.Intersects(Circle) so i moved all the math to a static function that just has Intersects(T1,T2) and switch on the two types which are restricted to `IGeometry`... it seemed cleaner.

Comment: Your definitions of `Translate` and `MoveTo` don't match the definitions in `IGeometry`. You need to add those constraints that you have on the interface definition (`where T : IGeometry;` ). Your generic definitions are funky; `T` is only a return type (it doesn't get involves in type inference since it's not involved in the parameter definitions) and, it's defined separately on each method, not on the interface. The result is you need to be explicit. Give it a try, and let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require a non-generic with generic versions of the members then you really need two interfaces. This is one of the circumstances where shadowing methods is necessary.

Try these:

```
public interface IGeometry
{
    IGeometry Translate(in v2 vector);
    IGeometry MoveTo(in v2 vector);
}

public interface IGeometry<T> : IGeometry where T : IGeometry<T>
{
    new T Translate(in v2 vector);
    new T MoveTo(in v2 vector);
}
```

Now you can implement the generic interface implicitly and the non-generic interface explicitly.

```
public readonly struct Circle : IGeometry<Circle>
{
    private readonly v2 _o;
    private readonly double _r, _area, _circum;
    public v2 Origin => _o;
    public double Radius => _r;
    public double Circumference => _circum;

    public Circle(in v2 origin, in double radius)
    {
        _o = origin;
        _r = radius;
        _area = _r * _r * Math.PI;
        _circum = _r * 2 * Math.PI;
    }

    public Circle Translate(in v2 translation) => new(_o + translation, _r);
    public Circle MoveTo(in v2 position) => new(position, _r);

    IGeometry IGeometry.Translate(in v2 vector) => this.Translate(vector);
    IGeometry IGeometry.MoveTo(in v2 vector) => this.MoveTo(vector);
}
```

Now with all of that you can do this:

```
Circle circle1 = new Circle();
Circle circle2 = circle1.Translate(new v2());
IGeometry geometry1 = circle1;
IGeometry geometry2 = geometry1.Translate(new v2());
Circle circle2a = (Circle)geometry2;
```

Calls to the non-generic interface methods call the generic versions to keep type safety.

However, keep in mind that you could implement this legally:

```
public readonly struct Square : IGeometry<Circle>
```

You need to be careful not to.

Comment: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. Shame that there is no `where T : this` constraint possible

Comment: @Charlieface - That would be ideal as I have used this pattern a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

The interface itself should be generic, not the methods themselves, like so:

```cs
public interface IGeometry<T> where T : IGeometry<T>
{
    T Translate(in v2 vector);
    T MoveTo(in v2 vector);
}
```

Then your typed will implement the interface with that generic specified:

```cs
public readonly struct Circle : IGeometry<Circle>
```

You can see this in the BCL's `INumber<T>` interface, which is implemented on all numbers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0